# This configuration file is essential to DNS resolution?

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, display-resolution, etc

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         files systemd
group:          files systemd
shadow:         files
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

I've been on too much wireless connection issues (reconnection and speed slowness). This file seems to be part of the problem.

```
uname -a
```

Linux black 5.8.0-51-generic #57~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 16 12:34:52 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
20.04.02
```

Comment: This is very unclear, I don't know what you're asking, nor what OS & release you're using  (FYI: my own file looks different to what you provided, but you didn't provide any release information).

Comment: I added some more  details about my release version.

Comment: I don't see any OS & release details sorry; kernel details are not the same as release details as kernels are used by more than a single OS, and what problem.  Depending on browser, the title may not be visible when page is opened...

Comment: You also haven't said if desktop (using NetworkManager), server (Netplan) or specialist release.... being specific helps us understand your issue.

Comment: Look at the logs! `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: What do you mean by "This file seems to be part of the problem"? What is the problem exactly?

Comment: The restart of the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Yes `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is essential. Read `man nsswitch.conf`.

Originally, Unix (pre-Linux) stored userid, passwords, hostnames, etc. in local files in `/etc`. When networking came along, some Unix systems managers wanted to get this information from the network (imagine updating a password on 256 different systems). Sun (SunOS, Solaris), with their "Yellow Pages" (later renamed "Network Information System") solved this problem with `nsswitch.conf`. It still works.

"nsswitch" is an acronym for "Name Service SWITCH"

Along with `nsswitch.conf`, the `getent` command, and the library calls `getpwent`, `getgrent`, `gethostent` provides programmer method-independent access to these quantities. Read the `man` pages for more information.